# Why the first line doesn't update ForeColor property?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've tried alter ForeColor of all rows of my DataGridView using this code:

```
private void dgv_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e) {
   if (e.RowIndex >= 0) {
      DataGridViewRow row = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex];
      e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
   }
}
```

But the first line doesn't receive update.

Has anybody else had this problems?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try in rowprepaint event ..

Comment: The CellPainting event is meant to paint something custom.  And only called when painting is required.  You are not painting anything.  The code belongs in whatever part of your program where you are adding rows.  Or the DefaultCellStyle property assignment.

Comment: @matzone At RowPrePaint I can't access the CellStyle. Thanks.

Comment: dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was:  the first line was select.
To fix just clear the selection of rows after update the ForeColor.

```
  private void dgv_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e) {
     if (e.RowIndex >= 0) {
        DataGridViewRow row = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
     }
     dgv.ClearSelection();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `CellFormatting` event

simply try this:

```
private void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, 
                            DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) 
{
      e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
}
```

see this picture.

[image]

Comment: I tried your code.
The header was updated but the first line continue without update. Thanks.

Comment: @monteirobrena try my answer now. however, earlier was also working for

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The picture you posted alert me to check if the first line was selected. So, I just clear the selection (dgv.ClearSelection();) and the code I posted works fine.